# Comparing password in my WinForms app to a password generated by Laravel 5

Tags: c#, php, .net, laravel, bcrypt

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have a web application built on the Laravel 5 framework where users have an account. I also have a WinForms desktop app built on the .NET framework that I want users to be able to log into using their website credentials. How do I go about hashing the password on the desktop app so that I can compare it to the password that was stored by Laravel in my user database? I currently hash passwords in Laravel like this: `bcrypt('password')`

Comment: I'm not sure about this but maybe you can use https://bcrypt.codeplex.com/ for direct comparison since bcrypt for .NET was based on blowfish. Otherwise, you might have to support another form of encryption that is common for laravel and .NET

Comment: First thing your `hashed` password is stored at the server, So you can simply create one `API` page in `Laravel` that check the password is entered by the user is wrong or correct. and then you can use `.NET` window app that can made the request on that `API` URL with username and password, So you can determine that user entered the correct or wrong password.